# how to implement a multisite kerberos authentication using omd/thruk

Tags: apache, kerberos

Hi I'm trying to create an omd (www.omdistro) multisite configuration which allows Single Sign On, I'm trying to do this using kerberos.
I have already configured system apache to use kerberos authentication on some directory and it seems to work, I tried to apply same kerberos settings to apache :

```
LoadModule auth_kerb_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_auth_kerb.so
```

into directory object :

```
    Options FollowSymLinks
  AllowOverride None

 Order allow,deny
        allow from all
        AuthType Kerberos
        AuthName <mine_auth_name>
        KrbMethodNegotiate on
        KrbMethodK5Passwd on 
        KrbAuthRealms <mine_realm>
        KrbServiceName HTTP
        Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/http.keytab
        KrbVerifyKDC off
        Require valid-user
```

But :

- in system apache configuration this produces a kerberos authentication
- in omd apache not and thruk prompts me login form

Is there a way to disable the login form in thruk ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a method that for now it works, I still have to try if I can play with users' permissions to limit what they can see.
For now, mine configuration, allows to everybody has a kerberos principal and performed on one site the authentication, to open all other sites.

First of all I disabled thruk cookie authentication that for some reason conflicts with kerberos one and shows you login form.

After that I loaded kerberos authentication module like described in my question, after that I discovered that there is a `site.conf` file in `${SITE_HOME}/etc/apache/conf.d/` that reading comments it is the one to modify globally site behavior, so I put in there the configurations about kerberos :
Omd site name is lab4

```
<Location "/lab4">
  # put your extra site configs here
 Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
 Order allow,deny
 allow from all
 AuthType Kerberos
 AuthName <mine-realm>
 KrbMethodNegotiate on
 KrbMethodK5Passwd on
 KrbAuthRealms <mine-realm>
 KrbServiceName HTTP
 Krb5Keytab /etc/apache2/http.keytab
 KrbVerifyKDC off
 Require valid-user
</Location>
```

I still have to test if I can use this configuration as a start to get a full functional user's access rules or not, I hope it could be useful.